# How to use RaVis Library? Some ideas?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, netbeans

I'va been monkeing with this lib : [Ravis](http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/wiki/RaVis).
It a librari on .swc, someone know how to use or configure this library on NetBeans 6.5?
I use Windows XP and Vista!

Thanks to all

Comment: Which Netbeans plugin do you use for Flex development? If it is Flexbeans, go into project properties and all additional library/source folders.

Comment: Another option, of course, is to checkout the Ravis source code into your project src folder and take it from there.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ravis with flex builder and I can use it just by dropping the .swc into my libs folder. Are you using any other libs with netbeans? If so, what's the error you get with the swc?

Also, it's open source, so you can compile it into your project as well if you want. Mine is at src/com/org/un/cava/birdeye.

Comment: I want to develop a web app, that create in a page a graph from xml (if it's ok).Can You help me Glenn?

Comment: Try using their examples and then adapt them to your needs. I won't be able to be much more help than that unless you have specific problems.